# Best Angular javascript Grid

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, datagrid, grid, spreadsheet

I need to implement a Microsoft Solution with Angular Js.
Solution have one Microsoft .Net Web Api for Crud operations, and MVC5 Project with angular js. I need an angular js grid where show data from web api json. I need i grid with paging and search. No inline editing functions.

I see ng-grid. Is it the best solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-grid is good. Lots of functionality it has. you can also use [smart table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/). Less functionality than ng-grid but too easy to use. the functionality you told I think all will be easily covered. Its a suggestion but [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/) is fantastic with a lot of functionalities.

Comment: Hi, I try to use jquery datatable (https://datatables.net/). In this application, I get all data from api and insert it into page. Is not a best solution because load all db data and render it. But work. Next step will be using  ui-grid (http://ui-grid.info/), new ng-grid version. I will try to load data from api function (paging it) .  Thanks to all!